# Powershell to export perms at site collection level

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions

I am looking for a ps scrip that connect to a sharepoint online site collection and export permissions info for all the contents below the site collection, can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article about SharePoint Online: User Permissions Audit Report for a Site Collection using PnP PowerShell for your reference:

[https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-user-permissions-audit-report-using-pnp-powershell.html#:~:text=SharePoint%20Online%3A%20User%20Permissions%20report%20in%20a%20Site,the%20risk%20of%20data%20leaks%20and%20compliance%20violations](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-user-permissions-audit-report-using-pnp-powershell.html#:%7E:text=SharePoint%20Online%3A%20User%20Permissions%20report%20in%20a%20Site,the%20risk%20of%20data%20leaks%20and%20compliance%20violations).

Comment: thanks a lot Julie.